# Как с помощью Python добавить инкрементируемый объект в MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

подскажите, пожалуйста:
Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE post(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                  term VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, 
                  term1 VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, 
                  PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Как с помощью Python добавить элемент в столбец `term` который будет образовываться по маске `url.ru/p=(значение из столбца id)` ?

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                    user='root',
                    passwd='1234',
                    db='db')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO post(term, term1) VALUES ("??????", "Текст для 3 
столбца")')

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

То есть первая добавленная строка будет выглядеть так: 
`id = 1, term = url.ru/p=1, term1 = Текст для 3 столбца`

Может быть можно использовать `cur.execute("UPDATE post SET term1='url.ru/p='")`? Только как-то после нее нужно вставить id у текущей строки

Comment: А зачем это нужно в БД? Хоть одна причина?

Comment: Хранение в таблице данных, которые могут быть посчитаны из других данных - это называется "переопределённые данные" и является потенциальной точкой рассогласования данных. Уберите вообще это поле, и считайте значение для него прямо в запросе, когда это значение понадобилось. Если сильно прёт - сделайте его вычисляемым виртуальным (или хранимым), см. calculated fields.

Comment: Можно копать в сторону LAST_INSERT_ID(), но я бы настоятельно рекомендовал прислушаться к совету Akina

Comment: А использовать команду `cur.execute("UPDATE post SET term1='url.ru/p='")` нельзя? Только как-то добавив после значение id у данной строки?

Comment: Никто не знает?

Comment: Дело в том, что если в ручную добавлять строку в бд, то id понятное дело инкремируется, а поле url.ru/p=, автоматом не заполняется, а мне нужно чтоб заполнялось, поэтому хочу сразу чтобы этот столбец при импорте заполнялся со значением id

Answer (score 0):

ID последней вставленной записи получите так: `id = cur.lastrowid`.

Но, если вы хотите сохранить недетерминированный результат, то как минимум нужно поле со штампом времени получения этого результата.

Если это не так, то полностью согласен с комментаторами, хранить в таблице данные, которые могут быть посчитаны из других данных, то есть детерминированный результат, не нужно. Удалите поле `term1`.