# Как из таблицы БД извлечь последнюю добавленную запись?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Можно ли это сделать с помощью `LIMIT`? Или можно ли извлечь запись у которой самый большой `id`, так как у каждой строки он автоинкемируемый, а значит самая последняя будет иметь самое большое значение в столбце `id`?

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 0,1')
```

Делаю так, но это самая первая строка извлекается.

Comment: Без явного указания сортировки, не определено какая строка будет "первой". И LIMIT 0,1 можно писать просто как LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одна запись с самым большим id:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: `WHERE ...` у автора не присутствует, нет смысла его добавлять в ответ (в зависимости от знаний, это может даже запутать)

Comment: @InDevX написал стандартный шаблон запроса. мало ли что у автора не присутствует. Запутать может при полном непонимании SQL, доки давно смотрели? Видели как там пишут примеры использования команд?

Comment: Доки там явно не для новичков написаны, которые не могут добавить сортировку. И к чему вы вообще их тут упомянули? Почему вы автора не послали доки смотреть? Нет такого понятия как  "стандартный шаблон запроса"

Comment: @InDevX мне кажется, или все (включая автора вопроса) всё поняли, только вам вот наверное нечем заняться кроме как комменты писать?

Comment: @InDevX упустил ещё один моментик.. а для кого доки написаны?? Например доки по командам SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT? Для проФФесионалов? Сами часто читаете такое? Посмотрите форматы записи примеров там

Comment: Они написаны для тех, кто умеет ими пользоваться и явно не для новичков. Нет, читал давно, пользуюсь буквально раз в год. Открыл [select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)'ы, там куча примеров и каждый описывается, а не просто добавляют что-то своё.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите получить последний `id`, сгенерированный на стороне MySQL сервера при помощи `AUTO_INCREMENT` (предположил что данный вопрос - продолжение [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1063266/211923)), то это можно сделать так:

после вставки в таблицу с `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ...")
```

можно использовать атрибут `lastrowid` объекта `cursor`, чтобы получить последний `id`, вставленный данным курсором:

```
cursor.lastrowid
```

или метод:

```
connection.insert_id()
```

чтобы получить последний `id`, вставленный в данном соединении.

PS роследний метод лучше использовать в том случае если приложение использует несколько курсоров для одного соединения.

Answer (score 1):

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Как здесь уже все указали, нужен ORDER BY и затем LIMIT 1. Добавлю только замечание, что строго говоря наибольший ID может быть не у той записи, которая вам нужна.

Если надо вычислить ID после вставки, то обычно полагаются на [cursor.lastrowid](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_last_insert_id.asp).

А если речь о самой свежей записи в календарном смысле, то логично делать сортировку по полю с датой

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY posted_at DESC LIMIT 1')
```